# Deleting account

Tags: support, user-accounts, delete

How can I delete my account?

I want to terminated my account but the tips in here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account do not help as there is no delete account tab?

Answer (score 3):

The delete button is only for users who haven't done much.
Other users should use the contact form linked at the bottom of that page.

> If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> Visit the [contact form](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.' After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions.